# How to store a database from PostgreSQL into a variable to use with PySpark inside a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: database, postgresql, dataframe, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

First log here.

I am looking for a way to store a database into a variable that can be modified with pyspark afterwards. I have seen options using Pandas' 'read_sql', but for given restrictions, the use of Pandas is not allowed and I can only worked with pyspark. I have the following paragraphs:

%load_ext sql

%sql %engine.run

%sql select from db

I already have connection with my databse from PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy, but now I need to store that database into a variable(dataframe) that can be modified with pyspark without using Pandas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.